asp-validation-for a DateTime is not working in Pop up Modal
Here's an example of how you can modify the code:

<form asp-action="AddFinancialTransaction" method="post" autocomplete="off">

    <input asp-for="CustomerID" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.CustomerID" />



    <input asp-for="FT_Date" type="hidden" id="miladi_date_FT_Date" data-val="true"/>



    <div class="form-group">

        <label asp-for="FT_Date"></label>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="کلیک کنید..." data-jdp data-jdp-miladi-input="miladi_date_FT_Date">

        <span asp-validation-for="FT_Date" class="text-danger"></span>

    </div>

</form>


By moving the hidden input for "FT_Date" outside of the date input, the ASP.NET validation should now be triggered properly. Try this modification and see if it resolves the issue with the hidden input and ASP.NET validation.When I use a hidden type of input in a bootstap Modal, the asp validation is not working
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="FT_Date"></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-jdp data-jdp-miladi-input="miladi_date_FT_Date">
    <input asp-for="FT_Date" type="hidden" id="miladi_date_FT_Date"/>
    <span asp-validation-for="FT_Date" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

As you can see, asp-validation-for="FT_Date" is never fired! For additional inforation I wrote "FT_Date" property
[Required]
public DateTime? FT_Date { get; set; }
I tried this code in a regular view page and it works well but it sounds like to not working in Modal Pop up bootstrap

I try as your code it works well.Which version of bootstrap do you use ? Can you give me the complete code about the  Modal dialog?
